# GameKit server disconnect makes session invalid

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gamekit

I'm trying to build a 4 player multiplayer game using GameKit. I tried many things and I'm currently using client/server mode, meaning that I have 1 session in GKSessionModeServer and 3 other sessions connecting to this one in GKSessionModeClient. My goal is, that when a user leaves the game or gets disconnected for whatever reason, that the others can continue their game. So far this works if any of the Clients leave the game, but if the Sevrer leaves the game, send and receive calls are not reaching the other peers anymore. I tried the same with 4 peers in GKSessionModePeer with the same result (where the player who accepts connections cannot quit). Does anyone had better success in making this work? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: GameKit is a part of the iPhone OS 4.0 beta, which is still under a strict NDA. Your peers will not be able to answer this question without violating their agreement with Apple.

Comment: I'm still using the 3.1.3 SDK and OS version. GameKit has been around since 3.0. I know that they are enhancing the API in version 4.0, but peer-to-peer networking using Bluetooth is part of OS 3.0 and already out.